# Javascript object property gets updated on assignment

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have created a JavaScript object like below -

```
var objtvar = {defaultPoints: [[0,0],[0,-10],[2.5, -10], [2.5, -10],[5, -10],[5,0]]}
```

I need to assign the *defaultPoints* property to another array and modify this new array. However on updating this new array, the object property too gets updated.

I want the object property to not change.

Code -

```
var objtvar = {defaultPoints: [[0,0],[0,-10],[2.5, -10], [2.5, -10],[5, -10],[5,0]]};
var flag = objtvar.defaultPoints;
flag[5][1] = 9;
```

This updates the values in both *flag* array and the *defaultPoints* property. I do not wish the property to get updated.

Updated Solution -
We can use the jquery extend suggested by @Nimrod Shory or use a pure JS implementation like this http://heyjavascript.com/4-creative-ways-to-clone-objects/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: Actually this is about cloning an array, and the question does not mention jQuery. The solution is changing line 2 to: `var flag = objtvar.defaultPoints.slice(0);`

Comment: @TudorIlisoi That's actually wrong because this is an array of arrays and because an array is a reference type it will change the old object.

Comment: indeed, it needs recursion. Mea culpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **deep clone** the object if you don't want to assign a reference.
You can do that with jQuery:

```
var flag = jQuery.extend(true, {}, objtvar).defaultPoints;
```

```js
var objtvar = {defaultPoints: [[0,0],[0,-10],[2.5, -10], [2.5, -10],[5, -10],[5,0]]};
var flag = jQuery.extend(true, {}, objtvar).defaultPoints;

flag[0][1] = 3;

$('#objtvar').text('objtvar[0][1] = ' + JSON.stringify(objtvar.defaultPoints[0][1]));
$('#result').text('flag[0][1] = ' + JSON.stringify(flag[0][1]));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="objtvar"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: This creates an object in which the array gets split into individual properties. Tried removing property 'defaultPoints' from the extend command, This does clone but the issue persists. The original objects gets updated on assignment.

Comment: @Manya - Edited my answer

Comment: is there a Javascript equivalent? I am using this code in Protractor UI tests which is based out of node js and the last thing I want to do is include jquery npm package

Comment: Got the answer -  http://heyjavascript.com/4-creative-ways-to-clone-objects/